# How to specify that the columns in a grid layout div should have a width equalling 100% of the parent of grid div

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface, css-grid

I have a parent div that contains a another div with a grid layout. The grid layout will have 1 row and arbitrary many columns.

How to specify that the width of the columns must be equal to 100% of the parent width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `grid-auto-flow: column;grid-auto-columns: 100%;`

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column; /* column layout */
  grid-auto-columns: 100%; /* all columns equal to container width */
  border:2px solid red;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.container div{
  border:2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, thx. What if I need the columns to have a max-width equalling 100% of the parent, but not fixed on it?

Answer (score -1):

When you define the classes for your divs in your CSS file, if you specify a width that width will be, by default, in relation to the parent container.

If you want to make sure, because some browsers may have different defaults, you can specify `position: relative;` in your definition.

example

```
.innerDiv {
   position: relative;
   width: 100%
}
```